# Is it possible to mark a release as succeeded if a manual intervention task is rejected?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently attempting to create an azure release pipeline for a service fabric deployment. I have a single stage for our test environment that contains multiple jobs/tasks.

After a deployment to the environment succeeds, we run integration tests and smoke tests.

After the smoke tests I have inserted a manual intervention task to allow Devs the option of running the regression tests (resume) or exiting the process (reject). **I would like to mark the release pipeline as succeeded if all prior tasks (deploy, integration & smoke) pass and the manual intervention is rejected.**

If the manual intervention is responded to with resume, then the outcome of the following tasks should determine the release pipeline result.

I cannot find an example of this, and therefore it feels like the incorrect approach. Would a better fit be to introduce an intermediate environment against which regression tests are run as a result of successful smoke tests?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: I did, and although the below should work, I don't like the idea of searching for a particular text in comments. So I have changed my approach and amended the way in which our pipeline works.

Comment: I didn't like also the searching the comments text, but is was only a direction how to achieve the goal. if it helped you, you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

By design when the user reject the intervention the release status became "Failed".

I thought a workaround for this issue:

1) The user always "resume" the intervention but the "comments" will be different.

2) After it, before the regression test add a PowerShell task to check the previous comment and set a new variable with the value "true" if the comments are kind of "run the tests".

3) In the regression tests task set a custom condition to run only if the new variable are equals to "true".

For example, if the approval resume the intervention with "Run Tests" the Regresstions Tests will be executed. so you need a PowerShell script that check what the approval wrote, if the approval text is "Run Tests" we set a new variable `runTest` = `true`:

```
$url = $(System.TeamFoundationServerUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/Release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)/manualinterventions?api-version=5.0
$header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:System_AcessToken" }
$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
$comment = $release.value.comments
if($comment -eq "Run Tests")
{
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runTest]true"
}
```

[image]

Then in the Regression Tests task you need to set a custom condition to run only if `runTest` variable is `true`:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['runTests'], 'true'))
```

[image]

Now, if the approval wrote "Run Tests" the tests will be executed:

[image]

If not, the tests will be skipped but the release will be "succeeded":

[image]

Note: for the PowerShell script you need yo allow scripts to access the OAuth token (check the checkbox in the Agent Job options):

[image]